# Issue Binding a List of Objects and there properties with Spring WebFlow 2

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Im having great difficult binding the value of a checkbox to an object thats nested inside a List during a post back.  Is there an issue with webflow and nested objects inside a list?.

jsp

```
<div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom: 8px;">
              <form:checkbox id="firmUserBeingEditedPermissionList[${status.index}].cascading" path="firmUserBeingEditedPermissionList[${status.index}].cascading" 
                onclick="toggleCascading(${status.index}, this, event);"/><spring:message code="setFirmPermissions.cascading" />
            </div>
```

flow.xml

```
<input name="userName" required="true"/>

<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="firmUserPermissionDetailViewBuilder.createFirmUserPermissionDetailView(userName)" result="flowScope.firmUserPermissionView" />
</on-start>

<view-state id="setFirmPermissions" view="admin/setFirmPermissions3" model="firmUserPermissionView">
   <binder>
       <binding property="firmUserBeingEditedPermissionList" required="true"/>

   </binder>
   <transition on="submitAddFirm" to="setFirms">
   </transition>
   <transition on="submitPermissions" to="viewAndConfirm"/>
   <transition on="cancelSetFirmPermissions" to="cancelChange"/>
</view-state>
```

firmUserPermissionView

public class FirmUserPermissionView implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7219027256643534729L;

public static final String KEY = "firmUserPermissionView";

private AbstractUser currentAdminUser;  
private AbstractUser firmUser;
private List<UserPermissionFirmDetail> firmUsersCurrentUserPermissionDetailList;
private List<UserPermissionFirmDetailFBO> firmUserBeingEditedPermissionList;
private Map<String, Collection<FirmSession>> firmCdAndExchangeSessionMap;
private Map<String, Collection<Firm>> firmCdAndExchangeSubFirmMap;
private Map<String, Collection<String>> firmCdAndExchangeExcludedSubFirmMap;
private Collection<String> exchangeSymbolsAvailableToLoggedInUser;
private List<PresentableFirmPermission> unSelectedFirmPresentablePermissions;
private List<PresentableFirmPermission> selectedFirmPresentablePermissions;

public List<UserPermissionFirmDetail> getFirmUsersCurrentUserPermissionDetailList() {
    return firmUsersCurrentUserPermissionDetailList;
}

public void setFirmUsersCurrentUserPermissionDetailList(
        List<UserPermissionFirmDetail> firmUsersCurrentUserPermissionDetailList) {
    this.firmUsersCurrentUserPermissionDetailList = firmUsersCurrentUserPermissionDetailList;
}
```

servlet

```
<bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
       <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean>

<flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"/>

<!-- This creates an XmlFlowRegistryFactory bean -->
<flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
       <flow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/flows/setFirmPermissions.xml"/>
</flow:flow-registry>

<flow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator" development="true"/>

<bean id="viewFactoryCreator"   class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
  <property name="useSpringBeanBinding" value="true"/>
  <property name="viewResolvers">
          <list>
                  <ref bean="viewResolver"/>
          </list>
  </property>
```

UserPermissionFirmDetailFBO extends UserPermissionFirm

```
public class UserPermissionFirm extends AbstractUserPermission {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long firmId;
private String brokerCd;
private String accountCd;
private boolean cascading;
private boolean supervisor;
private boolean authorisedForSessionCancel;
//used to store supervisor own entering Trader Id
private String enteringTraderId; 

private boolean inherited = false;  
//Permissions are 'disabled' if they have no sessions
private boolean pseudoDisabledForNoSessions;
private Long exchangeId;

/**
 * @return the cascading
 */
public boolean isCascading() {
    return cascading;
}

/**
 * @param cascading
 *            the cascading to set
 */
public void setCascading(boolean cascading) {
    this.cascading = cascading;
}
```

Comment: what's your error? do you have a stacktrace for us?

Comment: there is no error.  if I uncheck the checkbox the value does not bind to the model.  Its still true.

Comment: what does `UserPermissionFirmDetailFBO` look like?

Comment: I just edited the original post.  UserPermissionFirmDetailFBO extends UserPermissionFirm.  Theres multiple inheritence at work here.

Comment: May I add, nothing is binding, not even firmId etc etc

Comment: webflow binds the value when you submit not onchange

Comment: I am submitting the form.

Comment: @john have you solved this? :) after 5 years?